# What is the equivalent of DataMapper's child_key in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, datamapper

What is the closest thing to child_key from DataMapper in ActiveRecord? How would one write this using ActiveRecord?

```
   belongs_to :something, :class_name => Foo, :child_key => [:something_id]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read [here](http://datamapper.org/docs/associations)  :child_key is the foreign_key.  In ActiveRecord you use [:foreign_key](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-association-reference).

```
   belongs_to :something, :class_name => 'Foo', :foreign_key => :something_id
```

If I have misunderstood the purpose of child_key, please let me know.